# Cómo comprobar que un objeto está vacío en php

Tags: php, laravel, objeto

Necesito comprobar que esta variable está vacía, la cual aparece como objeto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando en Laravel 8, y `lastmonthtotal()` es una consulta sql (una funcion escalar). Cuando si hay datos devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tampoco me funciona @BetaM

Comment: como `$a->isEmpty()` y me retorna falso @BetaM

Comment: Por lo que se ve, la colección no está vacía, sino que tiene un objeto Mileage, igual que la otra colección que muestras, y lo que las diferencia es el valor de la propiedad TotalMes de ese objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma pude comprobar que era null:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se te ocurre una mejor, es bienvenida :)